# Compare columns of two different spreadsheet in excel and place result in third spreadsheet

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have say two sheets in same excel file.

Sheet 1

```
A
1
2
3
```

Sheet 2

```
A
1
2
0
```

I have been trying this till now `=VLOOKUP(Sheet1!$A2:$B$240,Sheet2!$A2:$B$240,2,FALSE)`

I get #SPILL! on doing the comparison, how do I compare two sheets and place the result in third

I needed this in my output

Sheet 3

```
A
True
True
False
```

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In sheet3 cell A2 simply put

```
=Sheet1!A2=Sheet2!A2
```

Then copy A2 down to A240 (or whichever is the max row).

You can also achieve an easy comparison visually using conditional formatting. Select all the data (A2:A240) in sheet1, click home > conditional formatting > New rule and set it up like this using a formula (be sure to use relative referencing A2 <> Sheet2!A2 and not absolute referencing $A$2 <> Sheet2!$A$2)

[image]

You can do the same on sheet2, using the formula =A2 <> Sheet1!A2

Comment: If you simply want to know how many cells aren't equal type this as an array formula (ie. dont just press enter but press ctrl + shift + enter) =SUM((Sheet1!$A2:$A$240<>Sheet2!$A2:$A$240)+0)

Comment: Also, level up with conditional formatting! I'll edit my answer.